# How can apply a perturbation method in a system of equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, perturbation-theory

If a have a system of equation

$$ \frac{d u}{dt} = 1- u e^{\epsilon(q-1)}$$

$$ \frac{d q}{dt} =  u e^{\epsilon(q-1)}-q$$

$u(0)=q(0)= 0$

How Can I apply the perturbation methot

$\epsilon$ small parameter

Comment: Expand the exponentials with a power series.

Comment: Ok,  but when I solve the equations one by one. Or one equation have relation whit the other. 


$$u(t)=u_0(t)+\epsilonu_1(t)$$

I know the power series of $e^{\epsilon(q-1)}$ is  $1 + \epsilon(q-1)+ 0.5\epsilon^2(q-1)^2$

when I introduce the previous  power series in the first equation


$$u'_0+u_0-1 +\epsilon (u'_1+u_0(q-1)+u_1)+ \epsilon^2 (u_0(q-1)^2+u_0(q-1)+u_1)+ O(\epsilon^3)=0$$

I can solve this but have some relation whit the other equation?

Comment: First introduce the new variable $q-1$.

Comment: Do the same thing with $q$ (or $q-1$), write $q=q_0+\epsilon q_1+\dots$ and substitute in.